# Как заполнить вектор

Tags: c++

Не могу понять как заполнить вектор

```
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    std::vector<int> myVector(10);

    int x, eps = 1000;
    cin >> x;
    double result;
    unsigned int a = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < myVector.size(); i++) {
        result = -x / (i + 1);
        if ((fabs(-x / (i + 2) - (result))) < eps)
        {
            break;
        }
        myVector[i] = result;
    }

    for(int i=0; i < myVector.size(); i++){
    cout << myVector.at(i) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Сформулируйте задачу. Чем заполнять? что вы хотите получить? Без внятного ТЗ результат один - ХЗ...

Comment: Берётся среднестатистический вектор. Делается аккуратно отверстие со стороны где нет стрелочки, и через отверстие выскабливается всё из вектора, оставляя тоненькие стеночки. Далее, берётся мешок наполнителя для векторов, и засыпается в проделанное ранее отверстие (можно применять лопатку, можно попытаться засыпать через воронку). Если Наполнитель перестаёт засыпаться в вектор, это ключевой момент, который даёт вам знать что вектор успешно заполнен.

Comment: Вы выходите из цикла по `break` судя по всему. На первой же итерации.

Comment: если  x >= eps, то вы сможете инициализировать только один элемент вектора по вашему условию, а чтобы инициализировать 10 элементов, то  x должен быть не меньше  eps * 10* 11 / 3 , а это примерно 37000...

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на вопрос "как заполнить вектор?" дает решение неравенства:
`((-x/i+2)) - (-x/i+1)) < eps, при i[0,10), eps = 1000`